# Vscode / Java Extension / Test Panel : How to specify runtime file.encoding

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, testing, encoding

I am attempting to set the file.encoding to iso8859-15 when running Java JUnit5 tests through the Test Panel of Visual Studio Code.

After consulting the documentation, I applied the following settings:

`"java.test.config": { "name": "MonConfig", // "vmargs": [ //     "-Dfile.encoding=iso8859-15" // ], "vmargs": [ "-Dfile.encoding=iso8859-15" ], "env": { "file.encoding": "iso8859-15" }, "classPaths": [ "${workspaceFolder}/agriscope-core/src/main/java", "${workspaceFolder}/agriscope-core/src/test/java" ] },`

While the classpath settings are recognized, I encountered an issue where the file encoding remains set to UTF-8 when utilizing the "launcher" in the Test Panel.

It appears that something is overriding the specified file encoding. It's worth noting that the project is a Gradle project, which successfully enforces the file.encoding as iso8859-15. When I run the tests using Gradle directly, there are no issues.

I would appreciate any insights into resolving this discrepancy between the expected and observed file encodings when using the Test Panel launcher.

Thank you.

I tried to force the file encoding in java.test.config.

Next I tried to look a java server log file, to see if something is wrong.

I see that Test Panel doesnot use gradle directly, but it launch the test by itself.

Comment: hello again. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1641

Answer (score 0):

A maintainer replied in your issue ticket that the code causing this seems to be in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/792249434fa8265a2b40d08956cc1b9dbe46e474/src/configurationProvider.ts#L362-L363

> ```js
> // VS Code internal console uses UTF-8 to display output by default.
> if (config.console === "internalConsole" && !config.encoding) {
>   config.encoding = "UTF-8";
> }
> ```

`config` is referring to [the setting of the same name](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/792249434fa8265a2b40d08956cc1b9dbe46e474/package.json#L473). That maintainer is currently investigating whether this is intentional. Sit tight and a fix will come if it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
 I'll wait for a while. 

I attempted a workaround by directly editing the TypeScript file in my environment, but I'm having difficulty finding the file by name or its content within my .vscode/extensions folder. (by grep/regrep... )... maybe it is still an encoding problem ( ;P )

I also tried an alternative method by forcing the settings in setting.json: "java.debugger.launch.encoding": "iso8859-15", but it doesn't seem to be recognized by VSCode.

Does somebody have a workaround plan...

Comment: @guillaumefernandez extension code for installation is minified. try searching for string contents, which don't minify. Ex. "`internalConsole`"